# Do I need egit for Android eclipse to upload to repository(github)?

Tags: android, egit, eclipse-adt

I use Android eclipse for developing. If I want to store my data to a repository on github.com. Do I need the plugin Egit for Android eclipse? Because I already see some version control features under "Team".

Comment: You bet you need it.  I had a really hard learning curve trying to do my first commit but I made it happen.

Comment: but doesn't android eclipse already have a built in tool?

Comment: I had to install it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that egit is already installed in Android eclipse. I just wanted to download egit from "egit - http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates" and I got the following response:

```
"Eclipse Git Team Provider" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
```

Here is a guide how to get egit: http://rayhanity.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/android-eclipse-with-git-egit/